# How to generate the code in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, mustache

I need to generate code from some array,the code should be generate according to the array value
for example,

```
alert("sofia")

alert("Miley")

alert("lindzy")
...
```

I've created for that array with the following structure

```
        var customerList = {
                cusomer: []
            };
```

and in the customer array there is name:value like name:sofia,name:Miley ....

The template look like

```
{{#each customerList.customer}}
    alert( {{name}} );
{{/each}}
```

And this is generate the Html with  {object,objet},what am I missing here?

The array look like

Comment: Try change alert({name}) to alert(name);

Comment: Are you trying to generate JavaScript code from JavaScript? Why? When will it be executed? Are you sure you're doing it for the right reason? Why not just call `alert` in a loop? Are you sure that your user can't provide some kind of malicious input so they can run arbitrary code?

Comment: Try to put your `customerList` declaration with data

Comment: And what is the content of your array?

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang-Thanks but since I use handlebars I must use it...

Comment: @Joe-Nop,Im using handlebars...this will generate an html file...

Comment: What if my name is `Joe"); document.write("my-insecure-script.js"); console.log("`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
customerList['cusomer'].forEach(function(e){
    alert(e.name)
});
```